# Can you control the weather with magic?

Tags: weather, sorcery-magic-kishuf

Can you control the weather with magic? Or is this only something God has power over?

Comment: Are you asking assuming that black magic can control other things? (I.e. would an answer stating that black magic does not exist be a valid answer?)

Comment: The performance of black magic is prohibited in Jewish Law.

Comment: Judaism does not deal with black or any other magic. This question is not about Judaism and off-topic. You might want to rephrase it to ask about Judaism.

Comment: @AlBerko How do you know Judaism does not deal with it? There is no *a priori* reason why Judaism couldn't deal with with magic. If you happen to know that it doesn't because you are an expert on Judaism then *that* would be the answer to this question, rather than makig it off-topic.

Comment: הכל בידי שמים חוץ מצנים ופחים

Comment: @Alex If you ask a question about the BM abilities you should ask it on its site. Otherwise, I proposed to rephrase it to link to Judaism. The current question sounds off-topic. ASAIK we don't have colors for magic also - black, pink yellow - I don't differentiate. He might ask about magic and Judaism in general like חרטומי פרעה but it should sound related.

Comment: @AlBerko Your issue is only that the question mentions the color black? I think that is a pretty standard way to refer to nefarious magic. And we have a tag for magic with 43 questions, so it seems on topic to me.

Comment: prohibitions against magic are written in the Torah and Gemaras talk about it, so its on topic.

Answer (score 5):

The Talmud records the following statement in [Taanit 2a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=2&format=pdf):

> אמר ר' יוחנן ג' מפתחות בידו של הקב"ה שלא נמסרו ביד שליח ואלו הן מפתח של גשמים ומפתח של חיה ומפתח של תחיית המתים
>
> R. Johanan said: Three keys the Holy One blessed be He has retained in His own hands and not
> entrusted to the hand of any messenger, namely, the Key of Rain, the Key of Childbirth, and the Key
> of the Revival of the Dead. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Taanith.pdf))

The simple reading of this might imply that no one and nothing other than God Himself has the power to control rain. However, it can be read in ways which are less restrictive, as Rashi and Tosafot there show, partially based on the parallel passage in [Sanhedrin 113a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=113&format=pdf). Rashi assumes that it means only that no one other than God will have all three of the keys; Tosafot assumes that it means that no one other than God will have any of the keys *at all times*.

Comment: thank for your ansewer, but what this makes me wonders is this a contradiction with Deut 18:10 raising of the dead, which is mentioned in the oral Torah.

Comment: @AsanRamzan Magic does not exist. So no, you cannot control the weather. And neither does G-d. Do you think G-d uses 'magic'? As if He cannot control the weather on His own. That would be insulting. Certainly, G-d need not anything to do His Will.